# Unable to post Attask custom data when creating a project

Tags: post, https, attask

Trying to use the Attask API to post a new issue to a project.  It works without posting cutom data.  This works fine:

https://ourcompany.attask-ondemand.com/attask/api/task?projectID=&&status=NEW&priority=2&name=Test%20Project%20FOOBAR&description=test&estCompletionDate=2014-03-28T09:00:00:000-0700

However, I'm unable to post custom data.  The url we use:

https://ourcompany.attask-ondemand.com/attask/api/task?projectID=&&status=NEW&priority=2&name=Test%20Project%20FOOBAR&description=test&estCompletionDate=2014-03-28T09:00:00:000-0700&DE%3ACUSTOMDATAFIELD=BLAH

The error we receive is:

{"error":{"class":"com.attask.common.InvalidParameterException","message":"category cannot be null","title":null,"msgKey":"exception.attask","attributes":[""],"code":0}}

I do not understand what it is asking.  The Attask API documentation is not helpful here.  What am I missing in my URL?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure you are making HTTP Post? Please elaborate on how you are producing the error

Answer (score 0):

You need to also set the categoryID to the category which has the custom data field.

```
https://ourcompany.attask-ondemand.com/attask/api/task?projectID=&&status=NEW&priority=2&name=Test%20Project%20FOOBAR&description=test&estCompletionDate=2014-03-28T09:00:00:000-0700&DE%3ACUSTOMDATAFIELD=BLAH&categoryID=XXXX
```

This is also assuming that you are doing a POST action.

Comment: Thank you jclawton.  I included the customform's categoryID in which the variables are defined.  Worked perfectly.  Thank you.